Can a CDF be non-monotonic?

The bus company from Blissville decides to start service in Blotchville, sensing
a promising business opportunity. Meanwhile, Fred has moved back to Blotchville,
inspired by a close reading of I Had Trouble in Getting to Solla Sollew. Now when
Fred arrives at the bus stop, either of two independent bus lines may come by (both
of which take him home). The Blissville company’s bus arrival times are exactly 10
minutes apart, whereas the time from one Blotchville company bus to the next is
$\text{Expo}( \frac{1}{10} )$. Fred arrives at a uniformly random time on a certain day.


What is the CDF of Fred's waiting time for a bus?

The answer states:

Let $\text{T}=\min(X,U)$ be the waiting time, where $X\sim\text{Expo}(\frac{1}{10})$ and $U\sim\text{Uniform}(0, 1)$. Then


$P(T\gt t) = P(X\gt t, U\gt t)$ = $P(X\gt t) P(U\gt t)$.

And to find the CDF:

$P(T\leq t) = 1 - P(X\gt t) P(U\gt t) = 1 - \exp(\frac{-t}{10})(1 - \frac{t}{10})$, for $0 \lt t \lt 10$ (and $0$ for $t \leq 0$, and $1$ for $t \geq 10$).

I understand the formulation, but I don't understand how $1 - \exp(\frac{-t}{10})(1 - \frac{t}{10})$ is a valid CDF, given that it's derivative is
$\frac{ d }{ dx }[1 - \exp(\frac{-t}{10})(1 - \frac{t}{10})] = \frac{\exp(\frac{-t}{10})}{5} - \frac{t\exp(\frac{-t}{10})}{100}$ = $(\frac{1}{5} - \frac{t}{100})\exp(\frac{-t}{10})$.
Wouldn't this mean that that the proposed CDF isn't monotonic, since for some $t$, the derivative is negative, violating the definition of a CDF?

Is it because $T=\min(X, U)$, so the max wait time is $t=10$?

Yes, since  $P(T\le 10)=1$ and  $P(T\le t)=1$ for $t> 10$.

A CDF has to be weakly increasing (and be càdlàg and have limits of $0$ on the left and $1$ on the right).
Since $P(T\leq t)=0$ for $t<0$ and $P(T\leq t)=1$ for $t>10$, you only care about $t \in [0,10]$.
Here $1 - \exp(\frac{-t}{10})(1 - \frac{t}{10})$ is a strictly increasing continuous function on the interval $[0,10]$, and is $0$ when $t=0$ and is $1$ when $t=10$. $P(T\leq t)$ is weakly increasing outside that interval.
Its derivative, the density, $(\frac{1}{5} - \frac{t}{100})\exp(\frac{-t}{10})$ is positive on that interval. Outside that interval, $P(T\leq t)$ has a zero derivative, giving a zero density.
So everything is fine here.
